# How to hide panels(Right & Left) from customize Log-in page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm working on Drupal 7 and trying to create one customize log-in page. Here i don't want to display Right & left panels in this page, its just like only log-in page which is having only header, footer and content where content would be `**Username and Pass fields**`.

**How to remove Or hide right & left panels from this particular customize page? Please help me out from this.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use the context module http://drupal.org/project/context, you can hide regions or blocks for a certain page